# Complexity of processing a collection's values

Tags: java, collections, complexity-theory

I need to store a growing large number of objects in a collection. While performing actions of each object of the collection, I regularly need to check whether an object is already stored. If an object is not stored yet I will add it to the end of the collection. I process each object iteratively while doing the checks.

Objects already processed should not be removed from the collection because I do not want put them back to processing when I stumble upon them again.

As a result I do not know what collection may fit best. HashSet has a constant time "contains" method but a List has faster methods to iterate over its elements, right ?

What would be the wiser choice ? Would it be relevant to keep two different structures at a time containing the same nodes, a HashSet for the checks and a LinkedList for the processing ?

Comment: The time to iterator over a List, Set, Queue, Deque or Map is much the same.

Comment: @Peter Are you sure ? These are interfaces, they cannot guarantee what complexity implementations of them will provide.

Comment: They iterate the simplest way to skip through all the elements. While there might not be documented guarentees, you can test them yourself and I would be surprised if you see much difference between them.

Comment: ArrayList tends to be the fastest Collection because all the references are in a linear array. But the order will be the same for LinkedList and HashSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use ArrayList, not LinkedList. LinkedLists consume a lot of memory, and it's slower on iteration than ArrayList.

2) I'd suggest to use two data structures. E.g. for the sake of you being unable to add to a collection wile iterating through it (ConcurrentModificationException)

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks for the ArrayList tip. I am afraid though that two structures are quite an inelegant way to handle the problem..

Answer (score 3):

> **As a result I do not know what collection may fit best. HashSet has a constant time "contains" method but a List has faster methods to iterate over its elements, right ?**

How about a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)?

> *Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order)*

Comment: Interesting class, but the iteration complexity still remains high. Besides, I can not use iterator on such a class because I am adding elements at the same time, as Andrey pointed out. I am likely to need a class where I could iterate "manually".

Comment: No, iteration complexity is not high, as the LinkedHashSet maintains a linked list of the objects. It is just as "expensive" as iterating through a linked list. You can still use an iterator, collect the stuff you want to append in a separate collection, which you add to the original collection after iteration. (If you need to iterate over the new elements as well, then do this before adding them to the original collection.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you are interested in two views on your collection.

1. A queue like view, adding things to the end and inspecting them at the front.
2. A contains check

All those operations are well supported in different kinds of heaps, e.g. java.util.PriorityQueue

Comment: These operations are defined in the Collection interface, which is a superinterface to the List, Set, Queue, Deque interfaces. So it is quite obvious that they are supported. My question is _which_ kind of collection is the most efficient for my purposes.